# use the result from one query in another query

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by, aggregate-functions

I am very new to postgresql. I have a table which looks like this

```
NAME GPA SUBJECT
BEN 3.5 MATH
BEN 3.7 BIOLOGY
KATE 3.7 MATH
KATE 3.7 BIOLOGY
```

one query gives me the average gpa for everyone for all subjects.

```
select avg(gpa) from table;
```

result:

```
AVGALLGPA
3.8
```

another query gives the average gpa for each person.

```
select avg(gpa) from table group by name;
```

result:

```
NAME AVGGPA
BEN 3.78
KATE 3.83
```

now I am writing a query which counts how many students have avg better than overall avg.

```
select 
    count(case when avg(gpa)> avgallgpa then 1 
          else null end) 
from table;
```

how can I pass the result(the avgallgpa) from the previous query into the later query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a Sub-query.

```
select COUNT(*) from table 
group by name having 
avg(gpa) > (select avg(gpa) from table);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 select count(*) from (
    select name from the_table 
    group by name
    having avg(gpa) > (select avg(gpa) from the_table )
) t
```